# Regex infinite backtracking in Eloquent JS

Tags: javascript, regex

Why does the parser jump straight to `b` after it comes out of the braces, according to this excerpt, instead of visiting the `+` operator first?

> "*For example, if we get confused while writing a binary-number regular expression, we might accidentally write something like `/([01]+)+b/`*."
>
> [image]
>
> "*If that tries to match some long series of zeros and ones with no trailing b character, the matcher will first go through the inner loop until it runs out of digits. Then it notices there is no b, so it backtracks one position, goes through the outer loop once, and gives up again, trying to backtrack out of the inner loop once more. It will continue to try every possible route through these two loops. This means the amount of work doubles with each additional character. For even just a few dozen characters, the resulting match will take practically forever.*"

From http://eloquentjavascript.net/09_regexp.html#backtracking

Comment: Where do you have that citation from? It would be nice to have a link to the original.

Comment: http://eloquentjavascript.net/09_regexp.html#backtracking

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, it does the repetion first. The text is a bit misleading, it omits the part where you jump into the outer loop, as well the first retry of outer loop before attempting to match `b`.

So what happens step-by-step? Let's first match `/([01]+)+b/` against `"01b"`:

1. The first term `([01]+)+` is matched against `01b`.

   1. This matches the inner term `([01]+)` against `01b` and (we ignore the capture group)

      1. matches `[01]` against `01b`, which succeeds.
      2. It goes on to match `[01]` again, now on `1b`, which again succeeds.
      3. It goes on to match `[01]` again, now on `b`, which fails.  It backtracks and continues with `b`.
   2. After `([01]+)` suceeded against `01`, it goes on to match `([01]+)` again, now on `b`.

      1. which matches `[01]` against `b`, which fails. It backtracks and continues with `b`.
2. After `([01]+)+` succeeded against `01`, it matches the second term `b` against `b`. Which succeeds.
3. It reaches the end of the regex, and returns the match.

OK so far? We've seen two times backtracking here, where each `+` repetion failed to make another round.

Let's match `/([01]+)+b/` against `"01"`:

1. The first term `([01]+)+` is matched against `01`.

   1. This matches the inner term `([01]+)` against `01` and (we ignore the capture group)

      1. matches `[01]` against `01`, which succeeds.
      2. It goes on to match `[01]` again, now on `1`, which again succeeds.
      3. It goes on to match `[01]` again, now on the empty string, which fails. It reports back.
   2. After `([01]+)` suceeded against `01`, it goes on to match `([01]+)` again, now on the empty string.

      1. which tries to match `[01]`, which fails and reports back.
2. After `([01]+)+` succeeded against `01`, it matches the second term `b` against the empty string. Which fails. **It backtracks into the outer loop**.
3. The outer loop backtracks into the inner loop.

   1. The inner loop is innermost, and as it does have matched more items than its minimum requires it accepts to give up the last one. We're back at having matched `([01]+)` against `0` only, so we continue on `1`.
   2. The outer loop matches the inner term `([01]+)` - a second time - against `1` now and

      1. matches `[01]` against `1`, which suceedds.
      2. It goes on to match `[01]` again, now on the empty string, which fails. It reports back.
   3. After `([01]+){2}` suceeded against `01`, it goes on to match `([01]+)` again, now on the empty string.

      1. which tries to match `[01]`, which fails and reports back.
4. After `([01]+)+` succeeded against `01`, it matches the second term `b` against the empty string. Which fails. **It backtracks into the outer loop**.
5. The outer loop backtracks into the latter match of the inner loop

   1. which has reached its minimum of matches and fails to give them up.
6. The outer loop gives up the second match. We're back at matching `b` against `1`.

   1. which fails, and backtracks.
7. The outer loop backtracks into the first match of the inner loop

   1. which has reached its minimum of matches as well, and fails to give them up.
8. The outer loop fails to give up its minimum of 1 match.
9. The `b` could not be matched anywhere, the match fails.

Comment: I think you're overusing the word backtracking, but this is essentially the same as my answer was going to be,   The main point is that the quoted text was badly written (though I've seen much, much worse).

Comment: @AlanMoore: yeah, maybe I should've used it only for the repetions in this context. But basically everything that "tries again" with a different part of the regex does backtracking.